# Quebrar texto e armazenar em vetor

Tags: c, string, matriz, gerenciamento-de-memória

Pretendo que o programa consiga armazenar por linha apenas 1 frase. Sendo que cada frase é possível de ser terminada conforme os sinais que eu mostro no meu exemplo de código. Ele faz isso mas quando imprime na tela não imprime esses mesmo caracteres que indicam que deve mudar de linha.

```
int main() {

//char str[] = "Ola. Tudo bem?\n Sim e contigo?\n Comigo esta tudo bem! Que tens feito?\n Trabalho no projeto!\n";
char str[] = "Utilizador 1 --> Bom dia! Tudo bem contigo?\nUtilizador 2 --> Comigo tudo excelente. Que tens feito?\nUtilizador 1 --> De momento estou a trabalhar num projeto e tu?\nUtilizador 2 --> Eu tenho estudado uma nova linguagem, Java. Bastante interessante. Devias experimentar.\nUtilizador 2 --> Talvez experimente quando tiver algum tempo livre!\n";
char **matriz = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 255);
int caractere,coluna,i;
int linha = 0;
matriz[linha] = malloc(255);
for (caractere = 0, coluna = 0; str[caractere] != '\0'; caractere++, coluna++) {
    if (str[caractere] == '?' || str[caractere] == '...' || str[caractere] == '!'  || str[caractere] == '.') {
        matriz[linha][coluna] = '\0';
        matriz[linha] = realloc(matriz[linha], coluna + 1);
        matriz[++linha] = malloc(255);
        coluna = -1;
    } else {
        matriz[linha][coluna] = str[caractere];
    }
}
matriz = realloc(matriz, sizeof(char *) * linha);
for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", matriz[i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aí já começa complicar. Fiz alterações que resolvem o problema, mas nem sei se é o que precisa, não há uma definição clara do problema. Interpretei que toda quebra de linha deve ser apenas substituída. Os demais caracteres separam e quebram em seguida.

Mudei a estratégia do código anterior. Agora pega todos os caracteres e trata como exceção apenas o caractere de quebra de linha e outra exceção para tratar a reticências já que são 3 caracteres. Não pode comprar diretamente mais que um caractere, só se usar uma função auxiliar.

Não testei todas situações. Na verdade acho que muita coisa pode dar errado neste algoritmo se os dados não estiverem bem normalizados. Para fazer um algoritmo robusto daria bastante trabalho, já viraria um *parser*.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "\nUtilizador 1 --> Bom dia! Tudo bem contigo?\n\nUtilizador 2 --> Comigo tudo excelente. Que tens feito?\nUtilizador 1 --> De momento estou a trabalhar num projeto... E tu?\nUtilizador 2 --> Eu tenho estudado uma nova linguagem, Java. Bastante interessante. Devias experimentar.\nUtilizador 2 --> Talvez experimente quando tiver algum tempo livre!\n";
    char **matriz = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 255);
    int linha = 0;
    matriz[linha] = malloc(255);
    for (int caractere = 0, coluna = 0; str[caractere] != '\0'; caractere++, coluna++) {
        matriz[linha][coluna] = str[caractere];
        if (str[caractere] == '\n' || str[caractere] == '\0' || str[caractere] == '.' || str[caractere] == '!' || str[caractere] == '?') {
            if (str[caractere] == '.' && str[caractere + 1] == '.' && str[caractere + 2] == '.') {
                matriz[linha][++coluna] = str[++caractere];
                matriz[linha][++coluna] = str[++caractere];
            }
            if (str[caractere] == '\n' && coluna == 0) {
                coluna = -1;
                continue;
            }
            if (str[caractere] == '\n' || str[caractere] == '\0') {
                matriz[linha][coluna] = '\0';
            } else {
                matriz[linha][++coluna] = '\0';
                caractere++;
            }
            matriz[linha] = realloc(matriz[linha], coluna + 1);
            matriz[++linha] = malloc(255);
            coluna = -1;
        }
    }
    matriz = realloc(matriz, sizeof(char *) * linha);
    for (int i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", matriz[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TunBN6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fzrrghyy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SplitStringMoreSeparators.c).